# Any Idea how to do a cleaner way for a null check in Razor Pages display?

Tags: razor-pages

I have tried this, and it works, but isn't there a cleaner way? The Razor Page code segment is below and the Class with ViewModel below that. I'm not sure what else to provide.

```
@if (Model.Courses.Instructor != null)
{
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Courses.Instructor)
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        --
    </div>
}



namespace OESAC.Models
{
    public class CoursesVM
    {
        public Int64 OESACID { get; set; }
        public String CourseTitle { get; set; }
        public String Instructor { get; set; }
        public String Locations { get; set; }
```

And just in case I probably don't know what I am talking about here is the class that allows Data Annotations

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace OESAC.Data
{
    //[Table("Courses")]
    public class Courses
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 OESACID { get; set; }

            [MaxLength(120)]
            public String CourseTitle { get; set; }

            [MaxLength(50)]
            public String Instructor { get; set; }

            [MaxLength(50)]
            public String Locations { get; set; }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach. That's how you check for null within the Razor Page. An alternative would be to check for null in the handler method and show a different page if there is no data. But whether that is the "right" thing to do in your application is for you to decide.

Comment: Mike, can you make this an answer and I will check it off as the solution. I wasn't looking for not showing a page, I can probably get that to work using .any() function. I just had 36 fields and some of them looked better if no value supplied. Table allowed nulls. In SQL it would be an IsNull() function in the query. In MS Access a query could use NZ() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach. That's one way to check for null within the Razor Page. Another option is the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/index#null-coalescing-operator) `??`. You would use this is you want to provide a default value in the event that a nullable type doesn't have a value:

```
<span>@(item.NullableValue ?? "Default value")</span>
```

And then there's the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) `?`, which you would for example use to prevent a method called on a nullable object raising an exception in the event that the item that the method is called on being null:

```
<span>@item.NullableValue?.ToString()</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! Your first example, the "null coalescing operator ??" , was perfect. A lot smaller than my attempt. Short and sweet and Bob's your uncle! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Boo ya! Found this works too in the controller on my Razor Page code behind. I took Mike Brind's above answer and added it in the controller to the field (notice the "?? and value if null). Easy peasy. Good for null check too. But wait! There is more! Scroll down to below the code:

```
   public async Task OnGetAsync(String CEUType, Boolean Approved)
        {

            Courses = await _context.Courses
                .Select(p => new CoursesVM
                {
                    OESACID = p.OESACID,
                    CourseTitle =p.CourseTitle ?? "",
                    Instructor = p.Instructor,
                    Locations = p.Locations,
                    Dates = p.Dates ?? "",
                    CEUDWP = p.CEUDWP,
                    CEUDEQ = p.CEUDEQ,
                    CEUonsiteInstall = p.CEUonsiteInstall,
                    CEUonsiteOandM = p.CEUonsiteOandM,
                    MaxCEU = p.MaxCEU ?? "",
```

The reason I was getting null errors on page load is I went and but some DataAnnotation and ComponentModel validation in the Courses.cs file (Model). This little line of required validation throws a null error at runtime:

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Course Title is required")]
```

and here is the error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The data is NULL at ordinal 1. This method can't be called on NULL values. Check using IsDBNull before calling.
```

Sure, everyone's reply on Googling is do Null To String conversion. But where?

Well, my example shows where: "CourseTitle =p.CourseTitle ?? "","
Such elegant short hand requiring vary little text.
So I can put the DataValidation in, and use the above shorthand.
Funny how the new/edit validation throws an error at just record displaying.